# I've lost the numbers on the x-ticks of my graph, how do I get them back?

Tags: python, graph

This is my code to plot a graph with residuals; however, I've lost my x-axis tick numbers and I don't know how to get them back... Any help would be much appreciated. And sorry if the formatting of this thread is wrong, it's my first.

## Code:

```
pyplot.figure()

fig1 = plt.figure(1)

frame1=fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.8,.6))

pyplot.errorbar(xval, yval, yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, marker='o',markersize = 2, linestyle='None', color = 'black')

# Axis labels
pyplot.xlabel(' Height (m)')

pyplot.ylabel('Mass per second (kg.s-1)')

# Generate best fit line using model function and best fit parameters, and add to plot
fit_line=model_funct(xval, [a_soln, b_soln])

# Theoretical line
x = np.array(arange(0.07,0.15, 0.001))

y = (-2.61049E-05) + (0.005815772)*x

plt.plot(x, y, linestyle = '--', color ='r',linewidth = 0.7, label = 'Theoretical')

# Experimental line
s = (-4.43329E-05) + (0.006008837)*x

pyplot.plot(x, s,linewidth = 0.7, color = 'black', label = 'Experimental Chi Squared Fit')

# Set suitable axis limits: you will probably need to change these...
pyplot.xlim(0.08, 0.14)

pyplot.ylim(0.0004, 0.0008)

pyplot.legend(loc = 'upper left',prop={'size':10})

frame2=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.2))

difference = y - s

pyplot.plot(x, difference, color = 'black')

frame2.set_ylabel('Residual')

plt.xlabel('Height (m)')

plt.yticks(numpy.arange(-0.000010, 0.000010, 0.00001))

plt.xticks(numpy.arange(0.08, 0.14, 0.01))

pyplot.ylim(-0.000010, 0.000010)

pyplot.xlim(0.08,0.14)

pyplot.grid()


pyplot.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a small example of working code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The code you provide is mixed with formatting, doesn't include the `import` statements, and makes references to undefined variables such as `xval`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing frames, consider using subplots instead. As I see from the code you're attempting to have subplots with different height ratios. There are better ways to do this, for example with `gridspec`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[4, 1])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
plt.errorbar(xval, yval, yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, marker='o', markersize = 2, linestyle='None', color='black')
#Axis labels
ax1.set_xlabel(' Height (m)')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'Mass per second (kg$\cdot$s$^{-1}$)')
#Generate best fit line using model function and best fit parameters, and add to plot
fit_line=model_funct(xval, [a_soln, b_soln])
#Theoretical line
x = np.arange(0.07, 0.15, 0.001)
y = (-2.61049E-05) + (0.005815772)*x
ax1.plot(x, y, linestyle = '--', color ='r',linewidth = 0.7, label = 'Theoretical')

#Experimental line
s = (-4.43329E-05) + (0.006008837)*x
ax1.plot(x, s,linewidth = 0.7, color = 'black', label = 'Experimental Chi Squared Fit')

#Set suitable axis limits: you will probably need to change these...
ax1.set_xlim(0.08, 0.14)  #redundant by adding "sharex=ax1" 4 lines blelow
ax1.set_ylim(0.0004, 0.0008)
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left',prop={'size':10})

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax1)

difference = y - s

plt.plot(x, difference, color = 'black')

ax2.set_ylabel('Residual')

ax2.set_xlabel('Height (m)')

ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(-0.000010, 0.000010, 0.00001))
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0.08, 0.14, 0.01))

ax2.set_ylim(-0.000010, 0.000010)
ax2.set_xlim(0.08,0.14)

ax2.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have also added some consistency in the way you use `pyplot` and `plt` and removed some redundancies. Please go through the code side by side to see edits.

To answer your question, your x axis tick numbers are hiding behind the lower frame. As you have set height ratios to `0.8` for upper frame and `0.2` for lower frame, there is no space left for xticks.

Here is atleast something to go on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bottom "axes" (the "subplot" in the figure) is covering up the x-labels of the axes above.

You can see them again by making the bottom axes smaller

Use the line `frame2=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.1))`. (notice that the `.2` is now `.1`.

Your code doesn't run self-contained, but this is probably roughly what you're after:
[image]